# Error cross-referencing when tikz mode is graphics if exist

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am getting the error "Undefined control sequence" when using

```
\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}
```

and the label does not exist (It should produce a warning not an error, though because the references are not resolved in the first compilation, it will certainly produce error in the first run)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{cite}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize
    %\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}

\newcommand{\Eref}[1]{E{ }(\ref{#1})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
  ]
  \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \caption{Caption text}
  %\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

This reference to\Eref{fig:fig1}, fails.

\end{document}
```

It compiles well in the current form. After the first run, if you uncomment `\tikzset`... it produces an error. It happened after I updated my TeX Live to 2014 version. 
If you further uncomment the `\label`... after two runs it works well.

P.S. I am using `tikzscale` with external .tikz file, though in this MWE I just copy-pasted the `tikzpicture` environment (the error still exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the `external` lib (appears to be a regression, perhaps introduced in pgf 3.0.0).

I have fixed it, it will become part of the next stable. Perhaps I can ship a copy with `pgfplots` in which case it will be available earlier.